# List activity not working showing blank screen in android app

Tags: android, listactivity, android-adapter

I am trying to develop list view in my android app I wrote the following class 
 But the problem is it is showing blank screen 
 Actually the program starts like this it firstly has a blank screen for 5 sec and then it shows the list view But the problem is it''s not working

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {
String classes[] = { "NewscreenActivity", "example 1", "example 1",
        "example 1", "example 1", "example 1", "example 1" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try {
        Class ourClass = Class
                .forName("com.example.newscreentask" + cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Intent Intent(Menu menu, Class ourClass) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

this is the class for list view but it doesn't appear

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                Intent newtask = new Intent(Splash.this, Menu.class);
                startActivity(newtask);

            }
        }

    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

}

this is the class which holds it for 5 sec and then must starts the above class 
Thank you Raghunandan I got it working but the problem is this that when I click one any activity for example the newscreentaskActivity from menu class it doesn't show any results

another problem is that I can't remove  last Intent method because it show error in above Intent after = 
Please can you suggest me another way to set that cheese thing in a different way

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));
```

Remove

```
private Intent Intent(Menu menu, Class ourClass) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}
```